# Microsoft Graph: Crazy number of change notifications for sent message

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, change-notification

I am getting an insane number of change notifications from msft graph api.

For 1 created draft, I received >15 created and updated notifications.

For 1 sent message, I received >50 created, updated, and (strangely) deleted notifications.

I have read [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635975/multiple-change-notification-from-microsoft-graph) that mention that it is expected to receive multiple change notifications. But this seems like too much--a ton of unnecessary network traffic, especially after sending the 202 Accepted response code.

Is this level normal?