# Getting multiple change notification from graph api while sending URL's in Microsoft Teams channel message

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams, change-notification

I have been using graph API provided by Microsoft to subscribe to change notification for teams message.
It's all working fine for normal chat messages but when i try to send any message containing URL's it sends two/three notifications and sometime it works fine (sends only one).
I have gone through the docs and followd the protocals like sending 202 response conde to acknowledge the notification has been received as soon as i receive the notification and run other functionalities in another thread.
I couldn't find more info on for this inconsistent behaviour.

So far I tried to minimize the process after receiving notification on webhook receiver route by performing other actions like extracting channel,message id and retriving message in different thread and sent HTTPResponse of 202 as soon as i receive the notification.

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue as you mention above.
Meanwhile got the related thread, please have look into this-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412261/microsoft-graph-webhook-subscription-getting-multiple-post-to-my-notificationur/40876329#40876329

Comment: also, could you please share graph logs/error logs so that we are investigating from our end?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT actually i recently came to know that the subscription I was creating was accepting the change type of created,updated both and two notifications were due to the fact that teams first create URL message and again update it after reformatting I guess, that was creating an issue, it's currently working as I removed subscription at update message