# Microsoft graph change notifications with "updated" changeType: How do we avoid unwanted multiple notifications?

Tags: events, filter, microsoft-graph-api, change-notification

When I subscribe to changes in events of a user (here, a meeting room), I want to receive notifications in specific scenarios only:

- The event is created.
- The event is deleted.
- The start time or end time of the event is updated.

**Problem** : My endpoint receive multiple (useless) updated notifications, which are not related to time changes.
--> My endpoint is triggered up to 10 times more because of that.

**How do we avoid unwanted updated change notifications ?**

*Solutions found that did not fixed my problem* :

- [Accept to receive all update notifications and filter in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412261/microsoft-graph-webhook-subscription-getting-multiple-post-to-my-notificationur) : My function is triggered 10x more than what is needed, with a call to my db to check start or end or changeKey each time.
- [Use OData filter during subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-change-notifications-overview?tabs=http#refine-the-conditions-for-a-notification) : Seems to be useless without call to my db to have previous values.

Classic subscription used :

```
{
    "changeType": "created,deleted,updated",
    "notificationUrl": "{{sync-service-url}}",
    "resource": "/users/{userId}/events?$select=start,end,organizer,isCancelled",
    "includeResourceData": true,
    "encryptionCertificate": "{{encryptionCertificate}}",
    "encryptionCertificateId": "ID TEST",
    "expirationDateTime": "2023-11-15T22:11:09.952Z",
    "clientState": "secretClientState"
}
```

Than you for your help !